# How to scrape in the form of a table so lists become even

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium Webdriver (Python 3.0) to scrape data off this [website](https://www.bluebet.com.au/sports/Soccer/100).  All the data is scraped correctly however, it scrapes in the form of a list meaning there are 127 Team and odds and 129 Hrefs.  Unfortunately, this means the Href is not beside the Team and odds correctly in the excel.  Is there a way to get around this?

I have attached screenshots and my code is below.  Is there a way to adjust this to scrape as a table so that it knows not to scrape Href where no Team and odds visible?  I am migrating from Winautomation which had this feature to Selenium.

https://ibb.co/kMC0mk - Picture showing why the Href is not beside Team and odds
https://ibb.co/hh4rsQ - What the Excel looks like.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\ad\chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get('https://www.bluebet.com.au/sports/Soccer/100')

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

time.sleep( 15 )   

#Odds
langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table-grid__row:nth-child(1) .headline-wrap")
for lang in langs:
    print (lang.text)

time.sleep( 10 )

#link
langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.ctr--epsilon.soft > a[href*='/sports/Soccer/']")
for lang in langs:
    print (lang.get_attribute('href'))

time.sleep( 10 )

#Team
langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table-grid__row:nth-child(1) .place-bet__odds")
for lang in langs:
    print (lang.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @ChellWheatly, couldn't find a way to do this with CSS.

Try this xpath selector to scrape only the "Hrefs" that have content:

```
//a/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'table-grid')]/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'ctr--epsilon')]//a
```

(I've tested this on the real page with [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl))

Comment: I don't seem to get anything with langs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'table-grid')]/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'ctr--epsilon')]")
for lang in langs:
    print(lang.get_attribute("href"))

Comment: It's because the xpath selector I wrote is for the `DIV` tag, you have to find the `A` descendants.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example for that?

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Out of curiosity, how would it be written for  finding a descendants of div.

Comment: You're welcome. the `//` operator finds descendants of a current element, and you could do `//tagname` grosso modo. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths and the chrome extension I posted are good tools for fiddling with xpath expressions.

Comment: I quite like this solution and tried to implement this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043398/get-element-based-on-if-element-exists.  Know how to get this working?