# Find only links that are followed by outcomes

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Referencing [this page](https://crownbet.com.au/sports-betting/soccer), I'm trying to get all of the `n Markets >` links but ONLY those that are followed by odds. You may have to scroll through a few pages to see an example on the site or there is a screenshot posted below.

[image: screenshot of page]

From the screenshot, the links that I want (circled in green) are followed by odds (circled in red). I do NOT want the links (marked with a red X) that are not followed by odds (circled in yellow).

Is it possible to get all the `.purple-arrow` elements based on if `.bettype:nth-child(1) .bet-party` exists beside it?

Should be simple enough with following and preceding yet this is not giving desired.

```
//*[contains(@href,'/sports-betting/soccer/')]/ancestor::*[contains(@class,'bet-party')]/preceding-sibling::span['other-matches']//*[contains(@href, '/sports-betting/soccer/')]
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do. Please explain in words what you are trying to do with code. Are you trying to only scrape matches that have odds displayed or ? Also you need to post an [mcve]. Your code is trying to do too much which also makes it hard to narrow down what you are trying to do. Please edit the question and simplify it. Clearly state what you want to do (in words), expected outcome, and then post an MCVE of your attempt with the current output and expected output.

Comment: @JeffC Correct. So if I scrape //[contains(@class, 'bet-party')] and then //*[contains(@href, '/sports-betting/soccer/')].   The links will not be beside the bet party names which defeats purpose of data scrape.

Comment: I edited the question heavily based on your comments to clarify and simplify it. Please take a look and make sure I haven't misstated what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with XPath.

```
//div[@class='container-fluid'][not(.//div[contains(@class,'no-outcomes')])]//a[@class='purple-arrow']
```

Breaking it down

```
//div[@class='container-fluid']
```

Find a `DIV` that contains the class 'container-fluid'. These are the top level containers that hold the entire row of HTML for each match.

```
[not(.//div[contains(@class,'no-outcomes')])]
```

It must not have a descendant `DIV` that contains the class 'no-outcomes'. If the `DIV` has this class, that row has no odds posted so we don't want these.

```
//a[@class='purple-arrow']
```

and finally... return the link with the class 'purple-arrow'.

You can test this in Chrome dev tools using `$x()`.